Nuxt 3 deploy to hosting
I hosted my Nuxt 3 project at https://nuxt-deploy.mpetrosyan.com. When navigating from the main page to a post page, everything works fine. However, if I refresh the page while on a post (e.g., https://nuxt-deploy.mpetrosyan.com/posts), I get a 404 error.
I use npm run generate to build the project.
My app directory looks like this:
nuxt-deploy/
  ├── .htaccess
  ├── dist/


Here is my .htaccess file:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dist/
  RewriteRule (.*) /dist/$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^dist\index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /dist/index.html [L]
</IfModule>

I don’t have direct access to the Apache configuration. If I move all the files from the dist folder to the root folder, everything works, but I want to avoid this. How can I configure my setup to handle page refreshes correctly without moving the files?

Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

I think the problem is with your htaccess configuration.
The server is not correctly rewriting URLs for the Nuxt.js application.
You can modify the .htaccess file to ensure all requests are routed through the index.html in the dist directory.
Try replacing the existing rules with the following:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dist/index.html [L]


and now it redirects to the main page, and the page does not open
